# How can I make a conditional in a query using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to create a conditional in the query where if enabled = 1 or enabled = 2.

```
const existBusiness = await Business.findOne({
  where: { id, enabled: 1, enabled: 2 },
});
```

For example:
`if(enabled == 1 || enabled == 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

const existBusiness = await Business.findOne({
    where: {
     [Op.or]: [
       {enabled: 1},
       {enabled: 2}
      ]
    }
  });
```

More information on Sequelize operators is available [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators).